# Codeigniter foreach loop error

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I am getting a `foreach` loop error in codeigniter, it was working fine, but once I moved the project to a new hosting I get an error for the loop. Both servers are using PHP 7.2

Here is the first error:

```
Message: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

And here is the second error:

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

The backtrace says the error is in the controller, I have checked many times and tried many methods but still the same.

Using `is_array` PHP function wont help, as it only hide the error messages, but the functions wont work as before.

Controller:

```
public function login(){
            $data['title'] = 'Sign In';
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            } else {

                // Get username
                $username = $this->input->post('email');
                // Get and encrypt the password
                $password = $this->input->post('password');
                // Login user
                $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);
                if($user_id){
                    // Create session
                    $user_data = array(
                        'id' => $user_id,
                        'email' => $username,
                        'logged_in' => true
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'Login Success');
                    redirect('users/account');
                } else {
                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login Faild');
                    redirect('users/login');
                }
            }
        }
    public function account($id = NULL){
      if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                redirect('users/login');
            }
        $data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_users($this->session->userdata('id'));
        $data['title'] = 'Account';
        $this->load->view('templates/user_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('users/account', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/user_footer');
    }
```

Loop code:

```
<?php foreach (array_slice($users, 0, 1) as $user): ?>
      <div><p><?php echo $user['first_name'] ?></p></div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Model:

```
public function get_users($id){
      $this->db->join('user_details', 'user_details.user_details_id = users.id');
      $this->db->join('user_orders', 'user_orders.user_id = users.id');
      $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
      return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Comment: show your get_users method also

Comment: How can you tell **Using is_array PHP function wont help**, are you sure about `$users` in `foreach()` is an `array()`. And, `is_array()` does not hides error, it prevents `foreach()` statement before executing & making error

Comment: @pradeep I added the get_users method

Comment: @Sinto I am sure about the $users, `is_array` prevent the `foreach()` statment, that's why adding it wont help. because if the `foreach()` is prevented how can I print the data on the screen

Comment: ok, i seen the query there. You do not need a foreach there because there is only only record from the query. avoid foreach & try echo $users['first_name'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the below code:

```
<?php foreach (array_slice($users, 0, 1) as $user): ?>
   <div><p><?php echo $user['first_name'] ?></p></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

as:

```
<div><p><?php echo $users['first_name'] ?></p></div>
```

Because:

```
public function get_users($id){
      $this->db->join('user_details', 'user_details.user_details_id = users.id');
      $this->db->join('user_orders', 'user_orders.user_id = users.id');
      $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
      return $query->row_array();
    }
```

This code will not return an multi-dimension array... you have used `row_array()` which will be a single array.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. it worked perfectly as before.